# Unable to download the code from Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

We are unable to download the code from Google App Engine. We tried with the below command: appcfg.py download_app -A -V  /destination --noauth_local_webserver

Error:
<ApiError 401, Message: "Rejected by creds_policy: Permission 'auth.creds.useNormalUserEUC' not granted to app-engine-server@prod.google.com, because it satisfies none of the 3 rules granting that permission.;

Any suggestions please

Answer (score 1):

`appcfg.py` has been deprecated.

For possible alternatives on how to download your source code, see my responses [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68538760/15211203), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67352294/15211203) to similar Stackoverlow questions. You can also  look at the responses from others on those questions.

Another possible solution to downloading your App is via the `gsutil cp` command but it has its own limitations/challenges as I explain in my response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70777273/15211203) (refer to bullet 3 in the response).

Comment: when i visit the bucket, its showing as no contents

Comment: The links I reference in my answer (my responses in other posts) gives reasons why this might happen.

Comment: There were no contents in the storage bucket.
How to retrieve code from google app engine ??

Comment: You can't. The contents are gone. The link in my answer provides explanations (the files are only kept for 15 days unless you changed the setting to have it stay longer or never be deleted).